# What is the known form of this transcendental number theorem suggesting $e\times\pi$ is very unlikely to be algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, transcendental-numbers

Playing with some algebra using only the assumption that the algebraic numbers are closed under algebraic functions, I discovered it's easy to show that for any pair of transcendental numbers $t_1,t_2\in \mathbb{T}$ and the algebraic numbers $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, if we define the set $X$ by:

$X=\{t_1\times(t_2+\overline{q}): \overline{q}\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}\}$

then $\lvert X \cap \overline{\mathbb{Q}}\rvert\leq1$

This implies for example if we take $\{e\times (\pi+q): q\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\}$, at most one element of this infinite set is algebraic - giving some measure of just how unlikely it is that $e\times\pi$ is algebraic.

I thought this was kind of interesting and I was able to extend it in various ways such as showing $e+\pi$ is also almost certainly transcendental (since $\lvert\{t_1+\overline{q}t_2: q\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\}\cap\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\rvert\leq1$).

I'm not an advanced mathematician; I just like to work things out for myself so I often discover things like this which are already known, which I presume is the case here. So I presume this is a special case of some theorem already in use.  What theorem is it, and what field of maths is this? I'm guessing it's something like transcendental extensions of algebraic fields.

Comment: P.S. I'm aware no more than one of $\pi\times e$ and $\pi+e$ can be algebraic and this theorem can be extended to show that too.

Comment: The field of math is elementary number theory. The result is so close to the definitions that it probably hasn't attracted any attention. If $t_1(t_2+q_1)$ and $t_1(t_2+q_2)$ are both algebraic, then so is their difference, which is $t_1q_3$, where $q_3=q_1-q_2$ is algebraic, contradiction.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I said it was easy! So trivial in fact I didn't even include it in the question. But I never appreciated before how strongly it shows that $pi\times e$ is almost certainly transcendental. I hoped there might be some more general form with broader results.

Comment: @RobertFrost: I know that you didn't say that such probabilistic reasoning is valid, but anyway just for the record, the problem is that the answer is already fixed and absolute as long as you grant the existence of natural numbers and real numbers, so we can't apply probability to conclude anything. For all we know there might be some subtle deep connection between $π$ and $e$ that makes their sum algebraic! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture for a possible avenue to resolving the question about $π+e$.

Comment: @user21820 agreed but by the same token we can create a set $P$ containing $\{t_1(t_2+q):q\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\}$ and knowing that of every element in the set, at most one is algebraic we can say rigorously that in the absence of any further information, the probability of any randomly selected element being algebraic is $\leq\frac{1}{\infty}$. Of course there is no entirely random means of selecting an element but we can analyse the bias in our "random" selection process and deduce rigorously that the probability of any given element being algebraic is very low.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Yes for a randomly selected element, but no for $π,e$, which are in no way random. By the way, your use of "$\frac1{\infty}$" is at best misleading and at worst meaningless, but I'm ignoring that. Also, absence of information has absolutely nothing to do with probability.

Comment: @user21820 Agreed, selection of $q=0$ from $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ cannot be entirely random since no selection of a point from an infinite space can be *entirely* random.  More importantly, given that $q=0$ was selected, it becomes very unlikely that it was not a heavily biased random selection.

Comment: @user21820 not sure if you're trying to turn this into a battle for supremacy but this describes the importance to probability of how much information you have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability

Comment: Bayesian interpretation is irrelevant to your question. Probability is a very specific concept defined in mathematical terms and has zero relation to whether we know something or not. We might **choose** to **assume** that things in the real world (such as a shuffled pack of cards) are drawn randomly from some distribution, and calculate the **likelihood** that something (verifiable) is true, but the fact remains that the outcome is fixed and also unchanged by whether we know it. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2} = \frac{π^2}{6}$ with probability $1$ whether or not anyone knows it.

Comment: @user21820 what is the probability a particular roll of a dice was a 6?  What is the probability a particular roll of a dice was a 6, if you know it was a 6?

Comment: @user21820 lack of information is the single most important aspect of probability.

Comment: Sorry but you're getting it all wrong. You should not confuse between the mathematical structure, which we can define via measure theory, and the attempt to create a meaningful interpretation of theorems to assist us in handling/making real world decisions. Let me answer your questions in your second-to-last comment. (1) You didn't show me that the dice roll obeys the mathematical theorems. What if the universe is deterministic? (2) It is 1 if you know it is 6. It is also 1 if it is a 6 even if you don't know it.

Comment: The reason that Bayesian interpretation is irrelevant to your question is that whether $π+e$ is algebraic is either true or false in the standard model of arithmetic. So the probability is either 0 or 1, regardless of what you know about it. Finally, I'm just trying to make sure you have the right understanding of probability. If you don't appreciate it, just say so. I can't answer your question because I'm not an expert in number theory.

Comment: @user21820 An interesting assertion.  If I tossed a coin, covered it over and asked you the probability it's heads, your preferred answer is "0 or 1".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43808/discussion-between-user21820-and-robert-frost).

Comment: I'll be glad to continue discussion in the chat-room I've created above. Do ping me in the chat-room when you reply, so that I get notified.